# How to tell the java compiler to allow public as package name?

Tags: java, gwt, javac

In GWT code I use a java sub package called public that contains html/css/etc.. files.

I notice that the java compiler output doesn't contain this sub package and its content.

I want this because of testing purposes. Any idea how to tell the java compiler to include this sub package and its content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't... It's a reserved word....

Sorry.

http://www.jwrider.com/riderist/java/javaidrs.htm

**EDIT**

and

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Thanks @Joachim

Comment: I'd link to this version: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: I know it's a preserved word, but still, it can be used as package name (Eclipse will handle it as a folder instead of a package name btw). 
So why isn't it possible to tell the compiler to include this package in the compiler output (just like a resource (src/main/resouces), only I can't put this folder in the resource folder as it's used by gwt)?

Comment: @edbras: The compiler only use Java source files in a package (and produce class files), nothing else. You must use another program if you simply want to copy stuff to the output. (This is independent of the package name, though.)

Comment: True... Also, you probably know this, but avoid hardcoding non-standard practices into applications, you don't know that it will be supported in future releases in Java and it could be confusing to this inheriting your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, "public" is a reserved word and you can't use it.  You can probably use "Public", though.  (Not that I recommend it.)

Comment: I know that public is a reserved word, but still don't understand why a package with the name public isn't included in the compiler output. See comment above.

Comment: Don't think of it as a folder, think of how it appears in code: package my.namespace.public; or package my.something.class;, and then consider how you would reference something by fully qualified name with a keyword: it could look like double.long.package.public.MyClass, which doesnt make much sense. Your argument that public is a mostly useless keyword that couldn't make sense there is sane, but thats not how java works.

Comment: Yep, any component of a package name must be a legal Java name.

Comment: But I don't use the package name in my code. I understand that Java doesn't allow an illegal package name in the code, but I would expect that the compiler would include any package/folder during compilation.